# Don't automatically focus the comment text field on mobile devices

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, mobile-web

When you click the "add/show comments" link, the text field for writing new comments is automatically focused. This makes a lot of sense on a regular browser, but it has a very annoying effect on mobile devices.

Each time I click the link to read the remaining comments the on-screen keyboard expands. Most of the time I don't want to write a comment when I click that link, I only want to read them. This is especially true on a mobile device where writing is much more cumbersome than on a regular computer.

On a mobile phone I would of course use the mobile version of the site, but on a tablet the desktop version is the preferred one.

The automatic focus should stay for non-mobile devices, but it is very annoying on tablets and should be removed there.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed the "but on a tablet the desktop version is the preferred one" - this means the code would need to start checking the browser explicitly and start messing with lists... not sure it's a good idea.

Comment: @ShadowWizard there is already some browser sniffing to detect if the mobile site should be served. And there might be a way to change this behavior without detecting the device, but I don't know enough about this.